# Create sub query for temp column for comparison of values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create sub query from my secondz column I want to get only 30 second or 1 minute intervals so they come back as 30 or 0. I am trying to create a subquery or another AND statement to select only rows where secondz = 0 or 30.

```
SELECT TOP (1000) FloatTable.[DateAndTime]
      ,DATEPART(ss, FloatTable.[DateAndTime]) AS secondz
      ,FloatTable.[TagIndex]
      ,FloatTable.[Val]
      ,TagTable.[TagName]
      ,TagTable.[TagType]
      ,TagTable.[TagDataType]
  FROM [FactoryTalk_Datalog].[dbo].[FloatTable] as FloatTable
  JOIN [FactoryTalk_Datalog].[dbo].[TagTable] as TagTable
  on FloatTable.[TagIndex] = TagTable.[TagIndex]
  WHERE (TagTable.[TagName] = '[PLC]FI225'
  OR TagTable.[TagName] = '[PLC]FI250'
  OR TagTable.[TagName] = '[PLC]SS_FIT1109')
  AND TagTable.[TagIndex] = 17
  AND FloatTable.[DateAndTime] >= '04/01/2022'
```

Comment: This code is for `mssql` not `mysql`, kindly provide the sample output.

Comment: Whoops one sec...

Comment: I am not able to upload screenshot but secondz displays as the correct number of seconds from the date time. Then I want to use that column to specify if it is equal to 30 or 0 include those rows in the final output

Comment: "I am not able to upload screenshot" -> Would be great if everyone else wouldn't be, too, at least when asking SQL questions.

Answer (score 2):

If you need where the seconds are only exactly 30 or 0 (60), try a modulo division:

```
and datepart(second, FloatTable.DateAndTime) % 30 = 0
```

Comment: And for 1 minute just DATEPART(second, FloatTable.[DateAndTime]) = 0? That seems to work so far.. Just dont want it to break and have to go back and fix later...

Comment: I used this for just getting every 30 seconds:
AND DATEPART(second, FloatTable.[DateAndTime]) = 30